# Show "date modified" when selecting image in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

When I click on an image file, it shows the date taken at the bottom of the folder. How do I change it so that it shows date modified?

Comment: I doubt if this is possible, why not just add a column for that?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible without writing a shell extension. Explorer is taking the data from the JPEg's metadata. Replacing that would be counter intuitive, thus requiring an exceptional solution.

Comment: But in previous Windows, it would just show date modified? It's rather annoying when the most recent file says 2007 simply because that was when the image was taken.